# How to convert string to date format in athena

Tags: ddl, amazon-athena

I'm trying to convert the string to date format in athena. What formatting i need to use to convert it..

Date string i have in table:
10-Jul-2019 04:39:59

I'm using to_timestamp but it is not working

```
SELECT to_timestamp('10-Jul-2019 04:39:59', 'dd-J-yyyy HH:MM:SS') limit 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the DateTime type to better parse the string into a DateTime with Java syntax.
https://prestodb.github.io/docs/current/functions/datetime.html

If you also need to put the value into a timestamp, you can after the DateTime conversion, cast the result into a timestamp.
Here the full statement:

```
SELECT parse_datetime('10-Jul-2019 04:39:59', 'dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm:ss') as timestamp
```